# How can I send a string to a specific port using PHP?

Tags: php, port

I have to send a string from an HTML page to a specific ip and port address using PHP.

**Example:** clicking on a button(on my HTML site) should result in sending the string `"hello"` to port `7474` of ip `x.x.x.x`.

How can i do that with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [fsockopen](http://php.net/fsockopen) to open a connection to the port and get a filehandle, then use [fwrite](http://php.net/fwrite) to write to that filehandle.

You'll usually want to close the connection with [fclose](http://php.net/fclose) when you're done. PHP will close the connection for you at the end of the script if you forget.